# How to avoid a XSP/Domino Cross-Site Scripting Vulnerability?

Tags: xpages

It seems possible to inject javascript in a get request, when refering to the /xsp/.ibmmodres/ XSP/Domino resources.

Normally, when you try this at .nsf/  resources, you get a correct default or custom errorpage without XSS possibilities. Special characters are substituted.

Example: 
 - http://[server]/[path]/[dbname].nsf/%3Cscript%3Ealert%28document.cookie%29%3C/script%3E

Result:
HTTP Web Server: Cannot find design element

But refering to the /xsp/.ibmmodres/ resources, it yields XSS possibilities.

Example:

- http://[server]/[path]/[dbname].nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/%3Cscript%3Ealert%28document.cookie%29%3C/script%3E

Result:

- I get a 404 errorpage "Cannot load unregistered resource /"
- And it executes CSJS and shows for example DomAuthSessID !!

How is this possible?
Is there a way to avoid this?
Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article about how to avoid this:

http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8XS3MY

Answer (score 1):

Check your Domino version. It should be fixed in 8.5.3. FP2 (not fully sure about that) (but definitely 9.0 Beta).
Other than that [follow my instructions](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8XS3MY) and create some web rules:

```
Type of rule: HTTP response headers
Incoming URL pattern: */xsp/.ibmxspres/*
HTTP response codes: 404
Expires header: Don't add header
Custom header: Content-Type : text/plain (overwrite)

Type of rule: HTTP response headers
Incoming URL pattern: */xsp/.ibmmodres/*
HTTP response codes: 404
Expires header: Don't add header
Custom header: Content-Type : text/plain (overwrite)
```

Comment: Thanks for the rules. These are working. Although, It is not fixed in domino 8.5.3 fp3.