# Cross site scripting in Domino?

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a  Domino site that is getting highs for cross site scripting on app scan.

We don't have a license to run appscan.  Another group needs to do that (yeah big corporations :) ).  But I have noticed that the IE browser will complain too with a url as such:

http://myserver.com/cld/cldg.nsf/vwTOC?OpenView&Start=28
(ie will warn  you on crosssite scripting with such a url).

I noticed the notes.net forum  site does not come up with such an error in IE, when I try to inject script tags.  I guess it must scrub the url before the page is rendered?   How is this being done in the notes.net forum?  Is it done at server level or a database level?

I did found this thread

[How to avoid a XSP/Domino Cross-Site Scripting Vulnerability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989580/how-to-avoid-a-xsp-domino-cross-site-scripting-vulnerability)

where Steve  mentions his blog and web rules but the blog mentions that they are not needed in 8.5.4. and above.  Am I understanding that right?  If so we are at 8.5.4. Is there something I still need to do to scrub my url?

Edit:  We are at 8.5.3.  Not 8.5.4.  I was mistaken.  Our admin is going to try Steves's suggestions

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Steve's blog post is referring to specific vulnerabilities related to xpages.

Comment: I might be wrong but the blog does not mention xpages.  It does mentions framesets.  There are no frameset design elements in xpages though it could mean a regular harcoded html frameset.

Comment: Yeah our admin said he thought the rules were for xpages too. And if u look at the rules themselves looks like they reference xpages

Comment: Ah.  I think it's just that his example rules were for xpage URL patterns, but I believe the rules are a general feature.